# why spark python udf execution time 10x difference on different partition strategy?

Tags: apache-spark, dataframe, pyspark, apache-spark-sql, udf

I got **huge (over 10x~100x)** execution time difference between 2 jobs with only difference on partition strategy, wanting to know why :)

Observation:

1. repartition by partition number with equalized record runs 10~100x slower than 2.
2. repartition by column: phone_country_code
3. from spark history, only difference are 1. got minor larger(10~20%) shuffle read size.

My environment:

- Spark 1.6.1 on EMR 4.7
- Python 2.7
- submit job using pyspark

Spark Job:

- python udf to parse phone number for time zone info
- read data from redshift via spark-redshift and write back

code sample:

```
from pyspark import SparkContext, SparkConf
from pyspark.sql.types import DateType, TimestampType, StringType
from pyspark.sql import SQLContext
from pyspark.sql.functions import col, udf

conf = SparkConf().setAppName("extract_local_time")
sc = SparkContext(conf=conf)
sql_context = SQLContext(sc)
sc.addPyFile("s3://xxx/xxx.zip")

def local_time(phone_number, datetime_org):
    from util import phonenumber_util
    local_time = phonenumber_util.convert_to_local_datetime_by_phone_number(
            phone_number,
            datetime_org)
    return local_time.replace(tzinfo=None)

local_time_func = udf(local_time, TimestampType())

df = sql_context.read \
    .format("com.databricks.spark.redshift") \
    .option("url", "jdbc:redshift://xxx") \
    .option("query", "select * from xxx") \
    .option("tempdir", "s3n://xxx") \
    .load()


# df = df.repartition(12*10)    # partition strategy 1
df = df.repartition('phone_country_code')   # partition strategy 2

df2 = df.withColumn("datetime_local", local_time_func(col("phone_number"), col("datetime")))
df2.registerTempTable("xxx")
sql_context.sql("SELECT * FROM xxx") \
    .write.format("com.databricks.spark.redshift") \
    .option("url", "jdbc:redshift://xxx") \
    .option("tempdir", "s3n://xxx") \
    .option("dbtable", "xxx") \
    .mode("overwrite") \
    .save()
```

data sample:

```
phone_number, phone_country_code
55-82981399971, 55
1-7073492922, 1
90-5395889859, 90
```

My guess:

- some optimization on jvm-py level on udf that depends on partitions's record distribution?

Thanks for any further suggestions :)

Comment: phonenumber_util in strategy 1 need handle all country code, while in strategy 2 it only need handle part of the country code. Not sure how phonenumber_util aware this difference

Comment: Try to use `df.explain` to show the execution plan of the two approach.

Comment: First things first - if you want to compare runtime use the same number of partitions in both scenarios.